# Adding LESS Extension to Dreamweaver CS5.5

Tags: macos, less, dreamweaver

Work gave me a new Macbook Pro yesterday and I'm having a hard time getting Dreamweaver CS5.5 to work with my LESS files. At first, I was getting an error saying that it couldn't open the filetype, so I hit the Adobe help areas and user forums and found the solution about editing Extensions.txt and MMDocumentTypes.xml. So now I can open the files from my local files side panel, but not from File -> Open. And despite having it listed as a Style Sheet extension, code hinting and coloring isn't working. A bizarre twist is that now if I take out my edits to those files, DW still opens the LESS files without an error. Anyone have any ideas how I can get this fully operational?

Here are a couple of the articles I found in my research and followed as best I could:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/extend/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d117f53d6108-7fda.html

http://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/kb/change-add-recognized-file-extensions.html

Answer (score 1):

From what I tried today, it kind of makes sense to me now. I have it working on CS5. To get started, you should show all files on your computer. Spotlight (OS X) makes things super easy to find all instances of those files. Once you find it, CMD + R will reveal the parent folder where the file resides.

The "Extensions.txt" handles whether or not DW can open the file from the modal window/program menu. This file is located in 2 places and you should edit using "text edit" or another baside editing program:

- USERS/library/Application Support/Adobe/Deamweaver
  CS5/en_US/Configuration/Extensions.txt
- Applications/Dreamweaver/Configuration/Extensions.txt

To do that you just need to declare a new type:

1. As part of the "all documents" list you need to add your SCSS,LESS
   extensions
2. As part of the "stylesheets" list you need to add your SCSS,LESS extensions

`CSS,SCSS,LESS:Style Sheets`

The second file you need to EDIT, is under the folder "DocumentTypes" in CS6 I believe that folder has moved to:
USERS/library/Application Support/Adobe/Deamweaver CS5/en_US/Configuration/

However, in CS5, I found this folder in Applications/Dreamweaver/Configuration/
From here if you edit "MMDocumentTypes.xml" this file it should explain how those extensions you previously defined in "Extensions.txt" should behave. (Again, use a basic text editor).

I think somewhere on line 140 or so, you'll see the following:

```
<documenttype id="CSS" internaltype="Text" winfileextension="css" macfileextension="css" file="Default.css" writebyteordermark="false" mimetype="text/css" >
```

From here add "scss,less" to the 'winfileextension' and 'macfileextension'. Because you're on a Mac, you probably want to make sure its filled out in the 'macfileextension' attribute.

The result should look like this:

```
<documenttype id="CSS" internaltype="Text" winfileextension="css,scss,less" macfileextension="css,scss,less" file="Default.css" writebyteordermark="false" mimetype="text/css" >
```

Cheers!